# ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to CONVERT, not load, my model into CoreML, but it keeps giving me this error and I have NO IDEA how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
import keras
import coremltools

import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('machine')

print(model.summary())

output_labels = ['0', '1']

model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('machine', input_names= 
['text'], output_names=['output'])

model.author = 'Aarush'

model.short_description = 'My model'

model.input_description['text'] = 'Takes text as an input'

model.output_description['output'] = 'Prediction of CyberBullying 
sentiment'

model.save('xcodeModel.mlmodel')

ERROR:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-5bde9de3c9f8> in <module>()
      1 output_labels = ['0', '1']
      2 
----> 3 model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('machine', input_names=['text'], output_names=['output'])
      4 
      5 model.author = 'Aarush'

21 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    138             if cls is None:
    139                 raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name +
--> 140                                  ': ' + class_name)
    141         if hasattr(cls, 'from_config'):
    142             custom_objects = custom_objects or {}

ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform
```

P.S.

I have tried doing `import keras`, and `tf.keras` and also `createObject` but none of them are working. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206117/discussion-on-question-by-shenoyaar-valueerror-unknown-initializer-glorotunifo).

Answer (score 0):

The `keras` coremltools converted only supports `keras` models, not `tf.keras`. For this latter library you need to use the `tensorflow` converter, with this function:

```
coremltools.converters.tensorflow.convert
```

More information in the comments of the source code [here](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/blob/21e8b389f0e27040d6da4da6902f2be7ba4e7c01/coremltools/converters/tensorflow/_tf_converter.py#L33). You would also need to convert the parameters, as it takes a model filename (a .h5), not a model instance. For example:

```
import coremltools
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50

model = coremltools.converters.tensorflow.convert(
    './model.h5',
     input_name_shape_dict={'input_1': (1, 224, 224, 3)},
     output_feature_names=['Identity']
)
```